# Accessing external TCP stream

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, networking, tcp

Theory:
Let's say I have an application A, written in Java, that uses a TCP stream for client/server communication (it's on the client end in the relationship). Now, purely as an experiment, I am trying to create an application B, written in VB.NET, that would serve as a proxy for application A's network stream, allowing app B to read and write to the stream.

Is it, at all, possible to access such a network stream from another application, also taking the language boundary into account?

Comment: TCP is TCP, the language doesn't matter.  You can write a proxy in any language just about so I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, but if you're asking about the possibility of making a proxy server, then yes, it's possible.  The language doesn't matter, but the interface does (the way that the content in the stream is encoded).  For instance, Java typically serializes things into a stream using big endian (most significant byte of each byte sequence sent first), whereas .NET uses little endian (least significant byte of each byte sequence sent first).  Again though, as long as you're aware of how the data is actually encoded into those streams, you can write a decent proxy server.  If all that your proxy server will be doing is passing along data without caring what the data is, then you can just read a byte from one stream and write it to the other.  But if you're actually reading values (integers, strings, pictures, etc.), then you will be dealing with the endianness issues, because Java and VB.NET's default stream readers will read and write integers differently, etc.

There will be some complications if you want to actually edit the data instead of simply passing it along.  You'll have to deal with the client's and server's reactions to strange network behavior.  For instance, if Client A is a video game, and Proxy B injects a message to the server to "join the game", then you'll have to deal with the fact that the server is going to send "ok, you've joined the game".  When the client receives that message, it will most likely ignore it, because it had no knowledge that the proxy tried to join the game on its behalf, and will just assume the server made a mistake.